# What would be a mathematical rigorous definition of a memory address space?

Tags: memory, memory-management, ram, memory-address, virtual-memory

What is the exact definition of a memory address space?

Is it correct to name the set of all the numbers from 0 to the highest addressable byte the definition of an address space?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the an array of addressable memory units from zero to the highest addressable.

The memory unit is normally a byte but it can be another size. On old Sperry systems and TOPS-20, it was 36-bit words.